# RecyclerView in ScrollView. How prevent creating invisible items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to add RecyclerView in scrollview, creating viewholders just for visible items?

Comment: add more details for your problem then only we can answer properly.

Comment: Sorry. I have several views, recyclerview and several layout below and above it. I want to scroll them as one item, so wrap them to scrollview. But as recyclerview in scrollview, it creates holders for all items at start, even invisible. Can I create recyclerview, so it creates just visible items, and allows to scroll in recyclerview until I reach last item, then scroll to other views in scrollview?

Comment: You need to add visible items only in list of objects you are passing in recyclerview.

Comment: No, I want to use virtualization, even if recyclerview is in scrollview. But as I understand, it's impossible, so I decided to refuse scrollview and will handle scroll events to hide another views. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to put like this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/cart_recycleview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clipToPadding="true"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    app:reverseLayout="true">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```